# Common Italian phrases to honour the dead?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-request, phrase-choice

What are common phrases to use in Italian to honour or pay respect to someone who has passed?

Is "Riposa in pace" used (literally Rest in peace)?

Comment: To be clear: are you asking specifically about phrases addressed (ideally) to the dead, as opposed to those addressed to their living relatives and dear ones?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! I agree with @DaG: can you please clarify what exactly are you asking for?

Comment: I would like to join the others in asking for clarifications, and also point out that an example situation where you want to use the expression would be extremely useful to answer this question.

Comment: Yeah, such as phrases in English like "Rest in peace", directed at those who passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, "Riposa in pace" is used.

"(Che) la terra ti sia lieve" ("May the soil be light on you") is also used.

The first expression is more traditional and common (and it could sound more detached, generic and formal) while the second could be regarded as more friendly/confidential; but I don't insist too much on this distintion as this could be subjective and dabatable.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sit_tibi_terra_levis